# Visual Studio 1 Solution e 3 Projetos, é possível separá-los depois?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Estou usando o Visual Studio 2015. Nele percebi que posso ter 1 Solution e quantos projetos eu quiser (nesse caso estou criando 3).

Depois de pronto, eu posso exportar os .EXE separadamente?

Como fazer?

Obs.: Não consegui fazer um título melhor para a questão.

Comment: O que chama de exportar?

Comment: gerar o EXE para o cliente

Comment: quero gerar 1 EXE para cada project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ideia é justamente essa. A solução é uma forma de agrupar um conjunto de projetos que fazem sentido funcionarem juntos, o que importa mesmo do ponto de vista técnica e não apenas organização é o projeto. Cada projeto gerará uma unidade de código, pode ser um `.exe`, uma `.dll` ou mesmo uma `.lib` em alguns raros casos. Então os projetos são independentes mesmo.

Só não vá colocar todos seus projetos em uma única solução se eles não tiverem relação entre eles.

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/ide/solutions-and-projects-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2015&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Algumas formas de estruturar a solução](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ee817674(v=pandp.10)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Comment: e como eu faço pra gerar os EXE separadamente?

Comment: Se tem projetos separados, o *build* gerará executáveis separados. Já tentou fazer isto? É o padrão. Pode escolher quais deseja gerar  ou não: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bc3qw.png

Comment: obrigado, estou aprendendo ainda. ^^